# When opening a folder chooser for writing a file, is it possible to also let the user name the new file in the same chooser?

Tags: android

I need to have my users select where they will save a file and the set the file name for that file.

Is there a folder chooser like `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` on Android that will also allow the user to set the name for the file at the same time or is this something that I can only do on two steps (show chooser and then show something to set the name)?

Comment: This sounds like `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: That sounds perfect reading the description. Thank you.